# Content type header is not supported error message

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I have the following curl command on elasticsearch and it has token based authentication.

`curl -k -H "Authorization :Bearer eH8AII7j3e81zfvcIKe715FXsjZ5or3" -XPUT https://localhost:9200/school/student/1 -d"{/"name/":/"mohan/"}"`

But it is throwing the following error.

`{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also provide the [`Content-Type` HTTP header](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_content_type_requirements) in your request:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization :Bearer eH8AII7j3e81zfvcIKe715FXsjZ5or3" -XPUT https://localhost:9200/school/student/1 -d"{\"name\":\"mohan\"}"
                          ^
                          |
                   add this header
```

Also you need to escape the double quotes with backslashes `\` not forward slashes `/`